# Binomial coefficient definition

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Why is the definition of the binomial coefficient $${{m}\choose {r}}=\frac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-r+1)}{r!}$$

I'm not sure where the last term in the numerator came about. Why should there be a $+1$?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe work out a simple case and show to yourself why the +1 is there

Comment: $(m-1)$ is the **second** term, so $(m-(r-1)) = (m-r+1)$ is the $r_{th}$ term.

Comment: @trueblueanil thanks! your answer is the one that clicked for me.

Comment: please check my edit.

Comment: @drhab thank you for correcting the typo

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: @shoestringfries: Another way to see it is to notice that $m$ is the number of integers from $1$ through $m$. You want to throw away the first $m-r$ of them, so as to leave only the $r$ biggest. In other words, you’re throwing away the $m-r$ integers from $1$ through $m-r$. The smallest one that you keep must therefore be $m-r+1$.

Answer (score 3):

You want to have product of $r$ terms. Notice:

$1$st term is $m$ (or $m-0$)

$2$nd term is $m-1$

$3$rd term is $m-2$.

You can see general pattern telling you that 
$r$-th term is $m-(r-1)$, which is just $m-r+1$.

Another way would be to notice that if you have product of $r$ consecutive decreasing numbers starting from $m$, you have remaining $m-r$ numbers when going down to $1$. This means that your product should end at a number that is one "above" the $m-r$, which is $m-r+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Just as: How many numbers from $6$ to $16$? It is: 16-6+1